# jQuery getting values from multiple selects together

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've got the following code which basically when the value of the select is changed I want to be able to take the new value and add it to the already existing value (or minus it).

I'm having an issue actually grabbing the value. I have this to create the select lists:

```
      <li class="extraHeight">
    <asp:Image runat="server" CssClass="iconImageMove" ID="Image14" ImageUrl="~/images/icons/carpark_off.png" />
    <div class="flipWidth">
        <select name="access" class="change" id="carpark_off"  runat="server">
            <option value="0">Off</option>
            <option value="256">On</option>
        </select>
     </div> <br /> <p class="noWrap">Accessible Car parking facilities</p>
</li>

        <li class="extraHeight">
    <asp:Image runat="server" CssClass="iconImageMove" ID="Image15" ImageUrl="~/images/icons/parking_off.png" />
    <div class="flipWidth">
        <select name="access" class="change" id="parking_off"  runat="server">
            <option value="0">Off</option>
            <option value="33554432">On</option>
        </select>
     </div> <br /> <p class="noWrap">Customer Car parking facilities</p>
</li>

        <li class="extraHeight">
    <asp:Image runat="server" CssClass="iconImageMove" ID="Image16" ImageUrl="~/images/icons/staff_off.png" />
    <div class="flipWidth">
        <select name="access" class="change" id="staff_off"  runat="server">
            <option value="0">Off</option>
            <option value="8192">On</option>
        </select>
```

(There are a lot more but that gives you an idea)

I'm using the following jQuery to detect the change and try and grab the value but it's not working:

```
<script>

    var value = $("select").val()
    $("select").change(function () {
          alert(value);
        })

</script>
```

Any suggestions would really be appreciated!

Tom

Comment: What do you mean by it's not working? What isn't working? What's going wrong?

Comment: When you say its not working, what do you mean? Is the change event not getting fired or the value in the alert is not what you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only selecting the initial value. You need to get the value inside the change event.

```
$("select").change(function () {
 var value = $(this).val()
 alert(value);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You set your value before the change try this:

```
<script>
    $("select").change(function () {
          var value = $(this).val()
          alert(value);
        })

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Calling `var value = $("select").val()` will save the value of the first `<select>` element matched by the selector into a variable as it was when that code was run - it won't update when you change the value of that element.

Instead, what you can do is use `this` inside your `change()` callback function to refer to the `<select>` element that has changed, and get its value, like this:

```
$("select").change(function () {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this:

```
$("select").change(function () {
      alert($(this).val());
 })
```

You are only getting the value out once and then just displaying the same thing on the change event.

#### See working demo : http://jsfiddle.net/JsKeS/

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("select").change(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            alert(value);
        });
    });
</script>
```

which will attach your change handler to the select elements after the DOM has loaded them.
Also, the `value` should be scoped in the handler, or the value will not necessarily be updated when other `select` elements fire the change event.

Comment: While making sure the variable is limited to the scope of the function is a good idea, you're not going to "get the same value for all select elements when they fire the change event" if you don't.

Comment: Poorly worded, I apologize. Rephrased in answer.

Answer (score 0):

First of all wrap your script in `$(document).ready()`, so that it will be executed after the page loaded. Secondly get the value of select inside the callback:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var value = $("select").val()
    $("select").change(function () {
          alert($(this).val());
    });
})
```