# jQuery Select list, selected text value rather than the value

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

building on my last question [jQuery getting values from multiple selects together](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9191278/jquery-getting-values-from-multiple-selects-together)

I have the select list like:

```
  <select name="access" class="change" id="staff_off"  runat="server">
                <option value="8192">Off</option>
                <option value="8192">On</option>
  </select>
```

And I basically want to add or subtract the value of the options if it's off, subtract if it's on add it. It's going to be stored in a cookie (it uses bitwise)

The jquery I have is:

```
<script>

        $(document).ready(function(){
           var currentAccess = $.cookie("access");
        })

        $("select").change(function () {
            var currentText = $(this).text()
            var value = $(this).val()

              $.cookie("access", value, { expires: 24 });

              alert(currentText);

              alert( $.cookie("access") );

            })

    </script>
```

I'll do the addition in the change function. The thing I can't work out is how to get the text of the select to do an if statement (so if it's yes, add the value, if it's no, subtract the value)

Tom

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you're looking for the inner text of the selected `<option>` element, you can use the [:selected](http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/) selector to match it, then call the [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) method:

```
var currentText = $(this).find(":selected").text();
```

Or, alternatively:

```
var currentText = $(":selected", this).text();
```

Answer (score 7):

To get the text of the selected item:

```
var value = $("#staff_off :selected").text();
```

I'd also suggest (if you're using HTML5) that using the `data-x` attribute to store the flag whether to add or subtract the value would be more semantic. Like this:

```
<select name="access" class="change" id="staff_off"  runat="server">
    <option value="8192" data-factor="-1">Off</option>
    <option value="8192" data-factor="1">On</option>
</select>
```

Then to get your final value to apply to the total you simply multiply the `value` by the `data-factor` attribute.

Comment: You need a space between `#staff_off` and `:selected`, or you will end up matching the `<select>` element if it is selected, which will never happen.

Comment: Thanks for that, is there a way to use a global rather than ID (as the bitwise adds the values of all the select sup, and theres about 30 of them)

Comment: Assuming you're looping through each `select` you can use `$(":selected", $(this)).text()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `$("#staff_off").find("option:selected").html();`